# Imprimir RadioBotton de un GroupBox en un Label C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms, radiobutton

Tengo un `GroupBox` con varios `RadioBotton` lo que querio hacer es que al escoger uno el texto de ese `RadioBotton` se imprima en el `Label`.

Esto es lo que tengo de codigo,pero al probar seleccionar un `RadioBotton` no se imprime en el `Label`, ya intente merterlo a todos los eventos del `GroupBox` y nada.

```
  public void mostrarRazon()
    {
        foreach (Control c in this.groRazones.Controls) 
        {
            if (c is RadioButton)
            {
                if (((RadioButton)c).Checked == true)
                {
                    lblRazon.Text = c.Text;
                }
            }


        }    
    }
```

Comment: Es importante que muestres donde estás llamando a este método. Probablemente, lo mejor es que enlazaras el evento `CheckedChanged` de todos los `Radiobutton` al mismo manejador, y alli directamente leyeras la propiedad `Text` de `Sender` para ponerla en el label.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creo que estas usando el evento incorrecto, no es uno del `GroupBox` sino que debe ser un evento del `RadioBotton`

Podrias asignar el mismo evento a todos los radios para que lancen la misma accion, por eso se usa el `sender` para determina que control lanzo el evento.

```
private void radioButton_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     var radio = (RadioButton)sender;
     lblRazon.Text = radio.Text;
}
```

solo eso no necesitas iterar para ver cual esta marcado ya que el evento lo lanzara el control que se seleccion

Para asignar el mismo evento a todos los radio debe selecionarlos y presionar `F4` para ver la ventana de propiedades, alli seleccionas para ver los eventos y ubicando el `CheckedChanged` asignas el metodo que ya existe.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

asignas a cada radio el mismo evento

Comment: Ya intente usar el ese codigo y aun asi nada, tambien genere el evento 'CheckedChanged' en uno de los 'RadioBotton' pero solo imprime ese.

Comment: pero tienes que asignar el mismo evento a todos los radio, no es un evento por cada uno individual

Comment: Gracias no sabia como asignar el mismo evento a todos los radiobotton